# How can I open a new customized (color, font, etc.) Terminal window from the command line?

Tags: terminal

I'd like to open a new Terminal window in Terminal.app. I'd also like to be able to customize this window (color, text, etc.), based on one of my pre-defined defaults, or based on something else not yet set in Terminal preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> opens a new terminal **window**.
- <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> opens a new terminal **tab**.
- If you want to open something other than the default Terminal, use the techniques [here](http://blog.azizlight.me/having-fun-with-applescript-and-terminal-app/) to open a pre-defined Terminal setup. You can also do <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>,<kbd>i</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up the Inspector, then use up/down arrows, or type the names, which lets you choose a pre-defined Terminal.
- If you want a setup hard-coded and not yet known to Terminal.app, follow [these instructions](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040823015557368).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I added more to my OP. Could you help me with that also?